# Change the name of HREF link

Tags: php, jquery, href, mouseover

I have the following link

```
<a href="example.com" id="example1"> Go to example....</a>
```

Is it possible that when a body moves the cursor over "Go to example..." it changes to "Go to example One" , i am using php and jquery. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.hover()` helper is useful here, to prevent annoying event bubbling:

```
var elem = $('#examle1'), orig = elem.text();
elem.hover(
    function() { $(this).text('Go to example One'); },
    function() { $(this).text(orig); }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't be too difficult using jQuery:

```
$('#example1')
    .mouseover(function(e) { $(this).text('Go to example One') })
    .mouseout(function(e) { $(this).text('Go to example...') });
```

Remove the second bind if you don't need it to go back to "..." when the user moves the mouse away.

*Edit: Forgot about the mouseover helper method*

Answer (score 3):

Try this out..

```
$('#example1').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).text('Go to example One');
});
```

Ya missed the # I was trying to get in quick ;)

Comment: Since it is an id selector you have to use # in front of example1

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
    $("#example1").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).text('Go to example One');
    });
});
```

or you can use the **[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** function like

```
$(function(){
    $("#example1").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).text('Go to example one');
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).text('Go to example....');
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even do that with CSS only. You just need two elements in your link that you can address like:

```
<a href="example.com" id="example1"> Go to example <em>…</em> <span>One</span></a>
```

And the corresponding CSS behavior:

```
a span,
a:hover em {
    display: none;
}
a:hover span {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the PHP code

```
<span
class="trackTitle"> <a href="<?php print  "play/".$link;?>" title="Listen or Download <?php echo $hoverActual ?>"  onmouseover="javascript:changeTo('<?php echo $hoverActual; ?>');"><?php echo $fileName; ?></a></span>
```

where the Function changeTo is used, i want to change $fileName; .

Comment: Using event attributes like `onmouseover` is considered bad practice.